# Reusing http2 request/stream

Tags: go, http2

I want to ensure that I keep the using the same HTTP2 stream for all my requests. I am "assuming" the way to do that is to reuse the http request object itself ? And if so, I am confused by various discussion forums where some say request with body cannot be reused, some like this https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/75671/ (and the comments in client.go RoundTripper) seem to suggest that as long as we close the response body, we can reuse the request.

Does anyone know what is the verdict on that ? Can we reuse http2 request structure ? And if not, what is another way to keep using the same http2 stream without creating new ones ? Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Rgds,
Gopa.